# On Meteor, how can I validate with Collection2 on the client side?

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I always use methods to insert, update and remove. This is the way my code look just now:

Client side

```js
Template.createClient.events({
  'submit form': function(event, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var client = {
      name: event.target.name.value,
      // .... more fields
    }

    var validatedData = Clients.validate(client);
    if (validatedData.errors) {
      // Display validation errors
      return;
    }

    Meteor.call('createClient', validatedData.client, function(error) {
      if (error)
        // Display error
    });
  }
});
```

Client and server side:

```js
Clients = new Mongo.Collection("clients");

Clients.validate = function(client) {
  // ---- Clean data ----
  client.name = _.str.trim(client.name);
  // .... more fields clean

  // ---- Validate data ---
  var errors = [];
  if (!client.name)
    errors.push("The name is required.");
  // .... more fields validation

  // Return and object with errors and cleaned data
  return { errors: _.isEmpty(errors) ? undefined : errors, client: client };
}

Meteor.methods({
  'createClient': function (client) {
    // --- Validate user permisions ---

    // If server, validate data again
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      var validatedData = Clients.validate(client);
      if (validatedData.errors)
        // There is no need to send a detailed error, because data was validated on client before
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Invalid client."); 
      client = validatedData.client;
    }

    check(client, {
      name: String,
      // .... more fields
    });

    return Clients.insert(client);
  }
});
```

Meteor.call is executed on client and server side, but Meteor doesn't have a way stop the running on the server side if the validation on the client side fails (or at least, I don't know how). With this pattern, I avoid sending data to the server with Meteor.call if validation fail.

I want to start using Collection2, but I can't figure how to get the same pattern. All the examples I found involve the usage of direct Insert and Update on client side and Allow/Deny to manage security, but I want to stick with Meteor.call.

I found on documentation that I can validate before insert or update, but I don't know how to get this to work:

```js
Books.simpleSchema().namedContext().validate({title: "Ulysses", author: "James Joyce"}, {modifier: false});
```

I know the autoform package, but I want to avoid that package for now.

How can I validate with Collection2 on the client side before sending data to the server side with Meteor.call? Is my pattern wrong or incompatible with Collection2 and I need to do it in another way?

Answer (score 3):

In under 30 lines you can write your very own, full-featured validation package for Collection2. Let's walk through an example:

```js
"use strict"; //keep it clean
var simplyValid = window.simplyValid = {}; //OK, not that clean (global object)
simplyValid.RD = new ReactiveDict(); //store error messages here

/**
 * 
 * @param data is an object with the collection name, index (if storing an array), and field name, as stored in the schema (e.g. 'foo.$.bar')
 * @param value is the user-inputted value
 * @returns {boolean} true if it's valid
 */
simplyValid.validateField = function (data, value) {
  var schema = R.C[data.collection]._c2._simpleSchema; //access the schema from the local collection, 'R.C' is where I store all my collections
  var field = data.field;
  var fieldVal = field.replace('$', data.idx); //make a seperate key for each array val
  var objToValidate = {};
  var dbValue = schema._schema[field].dbValue; //custom conversion (standard to metric, dollars to cents, etc.) IGNORE

  if (dbValue && value) value = dbValue.call({value: value}); //IGNORE
  objToValidate[field] = value; //create a doc to clean
  schema.clean(objToValidate, {removeEmptyStrings: false}); //clean the data (trim, etc.)
  var isValid = schema.namedContext().validateOne(objToValidate, field, {extendedCustomContext: true}); //FINALLY, we validate
  if (isValid) {
    simplyValid.RD.set(fieldVal, undefined); //The RD stores error messages, if it's valid, it won't have one
    return true;
  }
  var errorType = schema.namedContext()._getInvalidKeyObject(field).type; //get the error type
  var errorMessage = schema.messageForError(errorType, field); //get the message for the given error type
  simplyValid.RD.set(fieldVal, errorMessage); //set the error message. it's important to validate on error message because changing an input could get rid of an error message & produce another one
  return false;
};
simplyValid.isFieldValid = function (field) {
  return simplyValid.RD.equals(field, undefined); //a very cheap function to get the valid state
};
```

Feel free to hack out the pieces you need and shoot me any questions you might have.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the schema to the client and validate before sending to the server. If you want to use Collection" you need to attach the schema to the collection and use the `insert` which is something that you don't want. So the best option, for your scenario, is sending the schema to the client and use it to validate.

Also reconsider using mini-mongo instead of using Methods for everything, it will save you lots of time and don't think your app is secure jut because you're using Methods.